# Store special characters as unicode

Tags: java, encoding

We have to deal with special characters frequently. Sadly no particular attention was paid to the encoding until now. As you can guess we always end up getting an encoding problem of one kind or another.

We are currently working on changing all special characters to unicode at the moment (in property files and in code (I know that this does not comply with good coding practise but we can't change this at the moment).

Now I am not quite sure how we should handel inputs from other systems with varying encodings, should we convert special characters to unicode and is there any good API or convention on how to deal with these?

Comment: You haven't given us *nearly* enough context to provide any sort of helpful answer. Note that *all* characters in Java are in Unicode. Which *encoding* you use when transferring text data from another source is a different matter.

Comment: What makes you say that when you hard code äüö in your Java Code and run it in a JVM enviorment that does not support the orignal encoding of the Source File, you get garbage even when the client supports that particular encoding. So I can't agree with you on the point that all characters are in unicode...

Comment: Also what information do you require to provide a helpful answer, essentially we have multiple sources that provide us with inputs and what I really want to know is if there is any particular convention on how to deal with these inputs containing special characters.

Comment: Please read the JVM and Java Language specifications. A `char` in Java is always, always, always a UTF-16 code unit. The encoding of the *source* is irrelevant to the compiled form. You could have some weird encoding that I'm completely unaware of, and so long as you *compiled* it on a machine with that encoding (and let the compiler know that) then it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean char is stored as unicode - I am referring to Strings...

Answer (score 0):

If you know the original encoding you can convert it by using

```
String orig = "Cp1250"
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, orig));
```

Where the string orig have to reflect this [table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html). Then you can do whatever you want in code, because Java stores it internally in UTF8. If you want to persist it again in different encoding you will use a dual `OutputStreamWriter` with explicitly specified encoding.